# Beamer article mode + amsart freezes latex

Tags: beamer, amsart, article

If i try to get an article from my `beamer` slide using `article` mode and `amsart` style, my compiler (pdfLaTeX, LaTeX) gets stuck in an infinite loop:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\title{Test}
\author{Test}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test}
Test frame
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Replacing `amsart` by `article` in `\documentclass{article}` makes everything work well.

If I remove `\title` AND `\author`  keeping `amsart` it also works... so

- is it a bug (from `beamer`)?
- is there a way to use `beamer` AND `amsart` AND keep the titlepage info?

Comment: Changing the order to `\documentclass{amsart}
\title{Test}
\author{Test}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}` seems to work (but maybe some other things might break?).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prepare a file named `beameramsart.sty` with the following contents:

```
\ProvidesPackage{beameramsart.sty}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\baa@keepamsart}[1]{%
  \@for\next:=#1\do{%
    \csletcs{amsart\next}{\next}%
    \csletcs{amsart@\next}{\expandafter\string\csname\next\endcsname}%
    \expandafter\appto\expandafter\amsartnames\expandafter{\next,}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\baa@restoreamsart}{%
  \@for\next:=\amsartnames\do{%
    \csletcs{\next}{amsart\next}%
    \csletcs{\expandafter\string\csname\next\endcsname}{amsart@\next}%
    \csundef{amsart\next}\csundef{amsart@\next}%
  }%
}

\baa@keepamsart{title,author,date}
\RequirePackage{beamerarticle}
\baa@restoreamsart

\@onlypreamble\baa@keepamsart
\@onlypreamble\baa@restoreamsart

\endinput
```

Save this file alongside your LaTeX document or in a place where TeX can find it; on a TeX Live distribution it can be the directory

```
~/texmf/tex/latex/beameramsart
```

where `~` stands for your home; on Mac OS X with MacTeX it would be

```
~/Library/texmf/tex/latex/beameramsart
```

Now your document can be

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{beameramsart}

\begin{document}

\title{Test}
\author{Test}

\maketitle

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test}
Test frame
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The problematic commands are saved before loading `beamerarticle` and restored afterwards; the way of saving them is a bit convoluted because of the reasons given by Joseph.

Comment: It works fine, so i can continue using \input{main.tex} in separate master files for article / handout / slides without having to repeat title & author in all master files, keeping DRY is great :-)

Answer (score 7):

This is what I would describe as an 'issue' in `beamer`, in that it's more properly a bug but one that it's not really safe to fix. What is happening is that `\title` is normally a very simple command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\show\title

> \title=macro:
#1->\gdef \@title {#1}.
```

but `amsart` redefines it as a 'robust' command. That is normally fine, but `beamer` makes a copy of `\title` and installs a new definition. When Till Tantau wrote `beamer`, he did not anticipate needed to handle robust commands, so the way that the copy is made then leads to a circular definition.

The reason I class this as an 'issue' rather than a bug is that at this stage (`beamer` has been in use for many years) it's not really possible to alter the code in this area without almost certainly badly breaking some documents. Thus all that can be done is to live with the problem. As pointed out in comments, setting the `\title` and `\author` before `beamer` gets involved is probably the best way out of this.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\title{AN Other}
\author{Test}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test}
Test frame
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```